# Flash AS2 _root.gotoAndPlay()

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have some problem with flash as2 coding. 
Problem is this:
my built a flash app that has 3 frames in total. I wrote `stop();` in second frame and root stopped on the second frame and movie clip in frame 2 starts to play. I want to `_root` goto third frame when movie clip reachs the 30th frame.

i use `_root.gotoAndStop (3);` in movie clips 30th frame but that didn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: I just did exactly the same as you have and everything worked fine. Check if your movie clip with 30 frames does't have a stop(). Check for typos.

Comment: can i send you the flv for your check because i did exactly what you said. it still didnt work

Comment: Edit your post with a link to the FLA file if you want. If the code amount is reasonable people will usually help. But don't hope that somebody will just do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's pretty simple, you are missing to point the right target, in your case, you are playing until 30th frame but inside a movie clip, and you want the action has impact in the _root wich means you need to point the root but...

But "_root" doesn't seems to work in your case, well... probably you have more than one scene, some times it mess a bit.

**use:**

```
_parent.gotoAndStop(3);
```

**instead of:**

```
_root.gotoAndStop(3);
```

Make sure that you are writing this in the frame actions, some times I didn't pay atention and I wrote the code in the mc actions.

Other thing, make sure you are working on AS2.

Answer (score 0):

```
_root.gotoAndStop (3);
_root.gotoAndStop(3);
```

You put a space?

Like mentioned above

```
_parent.gotoAndStop(3);
```

Will also work..

You can also do this in multiple nests,

```
_parent.gotoAndStop(3);
_parent._parent.gotoAndStop(3);
_parent._parent._parent.gotoAndStop(3);
```